# С одного масива скласть два

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251>null");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int*a = new int [n];
    int k=0, z=0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
        a[i] = -500 + rand() % 501;
        cout << a[i] << " ";
        if (a[i] % i == 0) {
            k++;
        }
        else { z++; }
    }
    cout << endl;
    int *b= new int[k];
    int* c = new int[z];
    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
        if (a[i] % i == 0) {
            b[i]==a[i];
        }
        else { c[i] = a[i]; }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        cout << b[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        cout << c[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause>null");
    return 0;
}
```

Дано один масив,нужно два масива в первом все простие числа ,в втором нет,что здесь не верно?

Comment: Может вы нам скажите, что не так с вашей программой? Вы то запускали не раз свою программу. А мы поможем ошибку найти. Первое что попалось на глаза: `if (a[i] % i == 0) { b[i]==a[i]; }`

Comment: @ПавелЕриков мусор в втором и третим масивом

Comment: @ПавелЕриков дальше мусор

Comment: Дебаггером не пробовали пользоваться?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков не помогло

Comment: Почитайте [тут](https://ravesli.com/urok-26-otladka-programm-stepping-i-breakpoints/) как отлаживать программы дебаггером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще ваш код не делает, того что вам нужно, то есть `a[i] % i == 0` не значит, что `a[i]` простое число.

Что за промежуток у цикла?

```
for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
```

У вас массив `a` размером `n`, происходит выход за пределы массива!

Нужно идти от `0`, до `i < n`. А внутри цикла, где происходит `a[i] % i` пишите `a[i] % (i + 1)`, чтобы не происходило деления на `0`.

Далее вы пишите:

```
b[i] = a[i] //аналогично с c[i] = a[i]
```

Но размер `b` или `c` не равен `n`, то есть опять выход за пределы массива.

Нужно сделать две переменные, которые будут отвечать за индекс следующего элемента в массиве для вставки.

```
int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
```

И писать:

```
b[i1++] = a[i]; //c[i2++] = a[i]
```

И теперь ваша программа запуститься, но будет работать не так как вам нужно. Потому что проверки на простоту я у вас не вижу.

Спонсор ответа: Дебаггер. Лучшее что придумало человечество для отладки программ.